# Determining maximum of an expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to determine the maximum of an expression analytically by first finding the point where it becomes maximum:

```
Reduce[D[pφ^2/(2 m R^2 Sin[θ]^2) +1/2 m R^2 ω^2 Sin[θ]^2, θ] == 0 && 
  m > 0 && ω > 0 && R > 0 && pφ \[Element] Reals, θ]
```

However, its not working. Any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your system in this way

```
$Assumptions = m > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && R > 0 && p\[CurlyPhi] \[Element] Reals (*Thanks to Bob Hanlon*)
gl = D[p\[CurlyPhi]^2/(2 m R^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) +1/2 m R^2 \[Omega]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2, \[Theta]]
Solve[gl == 0, \[Theta], Method -> "Reduce"] /. C[1] -> 0 // Simplify
(**)
```

The solution involves ConditionalExpressions, depending on C[1]. If you restrict `0 <\[Theta]<2Pi` you can set  `C[1]=0'

**addition** 
The functional depends only on `Sin[\[Theta]]^2 and 1/Sin[\[Theta]]^2` and can be maximized analytically (using "Halbwinkelsubstitution", parameter a,b)

```
J = TrigExpand[a  Sin[\[Theta]]^2+b/Sin[\[Theta]]^2/. \[Theta] ->2ArcTan [u\[Theta]]] // FullSimplify
Maximize[ J, u\[Theta]] /. u\[Theta] -> Tan[\[Theta]/2]
```

Comment: You will get simpler expressions if you also include the given assumptions

`assume = m > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && R > 0 && p\[CurlyPhi] \[Element] Reals;

Assuming[assume, 
 Solve[gl == 0 && assume, \[Theta], Reals, Method -> "Reduce"] /. C[1] -> 0 //
   Simplify]`

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: Thank you, I edited my answer